# How to find all github repos that I starred / cloned

Tags: github, search, repo

How to find all github repos that I starred / cloned, via API using `curl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still looking, this is the endpoint:

```
https://api.github.com/users/<your_username>/starred?per_page=<amount>&page=<num>
```

The thing is though that it won't work like this by itself, you need to specify a special header:

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.star+json
```

You'll probably also need to [get a token for your account](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and use it in another header, otherwise you'll get rate limited pretty soon (you can only make 60 requests per minute without token).

```
Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN
```

So everything combined in curl would look like this:

```
curl \
-H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.star+json" \
https://api.github.com/users/$USERNAME/starred\?per_page\=100\&page\=2
```

Max per page amount is 100. You'll get huge chunks of json formatted text with a lot of unnecessary stuff that you'll have to parse through with some way, e.g. grep or you could try [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/).

There's some [nice](https://gist.github.com/sebble/e5af3d03700bfd31c62054488bfe8d4f) [gists](https://gist.github.com/mika76/2dd7be2e982c7b12fc88445d8064fc4d#file-stars-ps1) with complete scripts to fetch starred repos, both for Bash (curl) and Powershell, pretty sure you can find more by googling.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer, with my +25!

Answer (score 0):

```
curl --user "caspyin:PASSWD" https://api.github.com/gists/starred
```

Comment: Is that stared ***gists*** instead?

Comment: Yes. Is that not what you were looking for? @xpt

Comment: ***"github repos"***, as put in OP